# Determine whether the Columns of a Dataset are invariant under any given Scikit-Learn Transformer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Given an sklearn tranformer `t`, is there a way to determine whether `t` changes columns/column order of any given input dataset `X`, *without* applying it to the data?

For example with `t = sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` there is a 1-to-1 mapping between the columns of `X` and `t.transform(X)`, namely `X[:, i] -> t.transform(X)[:, i]`, whereas this is obviously not the case for `sklearn.decomposition.PCA`.

A corollary of that would be: Can we know, how the columns of the input will change by applying `t`, e.g. which columns an already fitted `sklearn.feature_selection.SelectKBest` chooses.

I am *not* looking for solutions to *specific transformers*, but a solution applicable to all or at least a wide selection of transformers.

Feel free to implement your own Pipeline class or wrapper if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all your "transformers" would have the `.get_feature_names_out` method. Its implementation is discussed in the [sklearn github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/21308). In the same link, you can see there is, to quote @thomasjpfan, a `_OneToOneFeatureMixin` class used by transformers with a simple one-to-one correspondence between input and output features

Restricted to sklearn, we can check whether the transformer or estimator is a subclass of `_OneToOneFeatureMixin` , for example:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest
from sklearn.base import _OneToOneFeatureMixin

tf = {'pca':PCA(),'standardscaler':StandardScaler(),'kbest':SelectKBest()}

[i+":"+str(issubclass(type(tf[i]),_OneToOneFeatureMixin)) for i in tf.keys()]

['pca:False', 'standardscaler:True', 'kbest:False']
```

These would the [source code for _OneToOneFeatureMixin](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/d5e045fd600bf7f3edd984fe7f8599124a67f7f6/sklearn/base.py#L870)

Comment: Thanks, this exactly anwers my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial answer. Both `StandardScaler` and `SelectKBest` have `.get_feature_names_out` methods. I did not find the time to investigate further.

```py
from numpy.random import RandomState
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectKBest

from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV


rng = RandomState()

# Make some data
slopes = np.array([-1., 1., .1])
X = pd.DataFrame(
    data = np.linspace(-1,1,500)[:, np.newaxis] + rng.random((500, 3)), 
    columns=["foo", "bar", "baz"]
)
y = pd.Series(data=np.linspace(-1,1, 500) + rng.rand((500)))

# Test Transformers
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(X)
selector = SelectKBest(k=2).fit(X, y)

print(scaler.get_feature_names_out())
print(selector.get_feature_names_out())
```